# Union Opens, Deliveries, Bounces and Sents from pastmonth

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have one monthly automation by report that the report goes to ftp via CSV and after run an Import File that populates a Data Extension with the totally numbers of sents, opens, deliveries and others records. But by this way, i have a problem that the CSV is broken the last numbers when ends whith 0 (eg: 11,410 populates like 11,41).For me it's a problem because makes confusion for ther user.

I'm trying to create an SQL where i just need the totally sents, opens, deliveries and bounces. But i stop in the SQL below where when the eventdate get error with *"EventDate could not be bound"*.

My SQL:

```
SELECT
SUM(TotalSends),
SUM(TotalBounces),
SUM(TotalSends - TotalBounces) AS TotalDelivered
FROM
(SELECT 
JobID   
,MAX(row) as TotalSends
FROM 
(SELECT 
JobID
,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row
FROM _Sent ) f
GROUP BY f.JobID) s 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
JobID   
,MAX(row) as TotalBounces
FROM 
(SELECT 
JobID
,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row 
FROM _Bounce ) d
WHERE DATEPART(m, s.EventDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, s.EventDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
GROUP BY d.JobID) b 
ON s.JobID = b.JobID
```

My goal is create something like the image attached.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will be honest and I am not sure what most of your question is asking, but I tried to fix your query as best I can to provide `JobID | TotalSends | TotalBounces | TotalDelivered` for all that happened in previous month.

```
SELECT 
    s.JobID
    , SUM(ISNULL(s.TotalSends,0)) as TotalSends
    , SUM(ISNULL(b.TotalBounces,0)) as TotalBounces
    , SUM(s.TotalSends - ISNULL(b.TotalBounces,0)) AS TotalDelivered 
FROM (
    SELECT
        JobID
        ,MAX(row) as TotalSends
    FROM (
        SELECT
            JobID
            ,row_number() over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row
        FROM _Sent
        WHERE DATEPART(m, EventDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
        AND DATEPART(yyyy, EventDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
    ) f  
    GROUP BY f.JobID 
) s  
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        JobID
        ,MAX(row) as TotalBounces
    FROM (
        SELECT
            JobID
            ,row_number() over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row
        FROM _Bounce
    ) d
    GROUP BY d.JobID 
) b
ON s.JobID = b.JobID 
GROUP BY s.JobID
```

This should get you where you need to be based off your request.

1. I used ISNULL() in your calculations so that it would be `0` instead of `null` in your return, this should help remove possible errors in your math for TotalDelivered.
2. I changed your Inner Join into a Left Join so that any Sends that do not have bounces will still be included.
3. I moved your condition to only pull for last month into the subquery for Sent
4. I added `s.JobID` into your final Select statement to have a 'key' to attach your results to
5. I added an Group By at the bottom to accumlate it all on JobID

Comment: Hello, @Gortonington. Thanks for the help. I attached a image that how the DE i want.